# .htaccess get after ? (Question Mark)

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is my input url

`site.com/?product-43049-keep-kids-filet-children-shoe`

I want it to redirect into this

`site.com/productDetail.php?id=43049`

I have already tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ?product-(.*)-(.*) productDetail?id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match query string in `RewriteRule` you need to use `RewriteCond` with `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable:

Try this code:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product-([0-9]+)- [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /productDetail.php?id=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank its work :)
But `pinfo.asp?pid=96043`   `RewriteRule /pinfo.asp?pid=(.*)$ com_tr.php?id=$1 [L]`
This not work. What do you think?

Comment: You need to use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pid=([0-9]+)$ [NC]` for that rule.